# How to execute part of the code on document ready?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a click event in my .ts (.js)file. When user clicks I am making a ajax call to get data. On success I am binding this data to create dynamic kendo grids (number of grids vary based on the data.)

After executing the event i want to execute some code. But at the time of executing this code that particular grid is not available. How to wait till grid available then execute this code? jquery document ready in the same click event is not working.

```
$(chkBox).click(() => {
            var chk = $(event.target);
            var val = chk.val();
            if (chk.prop("checked")) {
                // code removed for bravity                                    
                proxyEle.getData(myObject).done(result => {
                // this div has partial view which binds data from result.
                    $(divGrids).html(<string>result); // this part creates kendo grids dynamcially based on data.

                    // here I want to execute my code on the grid elements 
                    //but this code is executing before grid creation is complete. 
                    //So my code is not working. Why here? My grid ids are 
                    // like "SomeConstName"+chk.val(); this val() I only get here.

                }).fail(error => {
                    // handle error
                });
                }
                }
```

Why execute my code there? because I am using grid id as "ConstGridName" + chk.value();

This Id value I am getting in the above code. That is why I want to execute my code there. How to delay my code execution until all grids are ready?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know when the grid is complete (and binded) is to subscribe the DataBound event (fired when grid is filled with data)

```
.Events(ev => ev.DataBound("onGridDataBound"))
```

There you can run your code.